# fetching the value from a map by index using Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using Underscore.js in my application. I want to retrieve the value from a map for a given index. I read through the documentation of Undescrore.js but did not find one. Can we get a value from a map object using the index in Underscore.js?

Comment: You mean like `map[index]`?

Comment: Yes. Fetching the value based on index.

Comment: Then why do you need underscore.js?

Answer (score 0):

For objects you can use _.pick()

http://underscorejs.org/#pick

```
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'name', 'age');
returns {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is built into javascript (and every other language that uses hash maps -- what else would a hash be used for?).

Simply using `map[index]` should do the trick. If you want the key based on the value, you can use `_.invert(map)[index]`.